# Difference between two timestamp variable in php

Tags: php

I have two timestamps let us say

```
 $end_date =  2014-09-09 15:03:10 and now date 
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
 $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I want to calculate number of days remaining .Suppose if that particular date crosses now date and it should display remaining days with -ve value.

I am using the following code

```
$remaining_days =strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($now) ;
$Result_days = floor($remaining_days /86400);
echo $remaining_days.'   '.$Result_days.'<br/>'
```

Problem is that if the end date = today's date it is displaying -1 . I want to calculate based on time and display remaining days and hours.
Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: @Clement Malet. I have gone through that thread. But it only displays remaining days but not with +ve and -ve offsets

Comment: I advice you to take a look at the Datetime object.. http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Akshobhya What do you mean by "ve offsets" ? I don't get it

Comment: I meant see suppose end date = todays date then we have to caluclate based on time and display remaining hours.suppose that time crosees today's time then it should say -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
$end_date =  "2014-10-09 15:03:10";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$diff = strtotime($now) - strtotime($end_date);
$fullDays    = floor($diff/(60*60*24));   
$fullHours   = floor(($diff-($fullDays*60*60*24))/(60*60));   
$fullMinutes = floor(($diff-($fullDays*60*60*24)-($fullHours*60*60))/60);      
echo "Difference is $fullDays days, $fullHours hours and $fullMinutes minutes.";
```

**Output:**

Difference is -30 days, 0 hours and 39 minutes.

**Demo:**

http://3v4l.org/3auqe

**Edit (using DATE OBJECT):**

```
<?php

// Example 1
$end_date =  "2014-09-11 20:35:10";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date1=date_create($now);
$date2=date_create($end_date);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2,FALSE);
echo $diff->format("%R%d days, %h hours, %m minutes, %s seconds").PHP_EOL;    
//Output:
+2 days, 3 hours, 0 minutes, 44 seconds


// Example 2
$end_date =  "2014-09-08 20:35:10";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date1=date_create($now);
$date2=date_create($end_date);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2,FALSE);
echo $diff->format("%R%d days, %h hours, %m minutes, %s seconds").PHP_EOL;    
//Output:
-0 days, 20 hours, 0 minutes, 16 seconds
```

**Demo:**

http://3v4l.org/dPSgX#vhhvm-320

Comment: Hi parag this is exactly what I was looking for but see try to change the end date to 2014-09-09 15-03-10 .Now it just displaying the remaining minutes but there is no -ve sign .

Comment: @Akshobhya:- If that is the case then you can simply add a check if the value is less than 0 then add a -ve sign to the number

Comment: @Akshobhya: Check edits

Comment: @Akshobhya: Check updates in edit.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `date_diff` php method .you can see example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
<?php   
    $dateDiff    = $date1 - $date2;   
    $fullDays    = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));   
    $fullHours   = floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24))/(60*60));   
    $fullMinutes = floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24)-($fullHours*60*60))/60);      
    echo "Differernce is $fullDays days, $fullHours hours and $fullMinutes minutes.";   
?>
```

See the [Source](http://forums.webmasterhub.net/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1831) for more options

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014-09-09");
$date2 = new DateTime("2014-09-12");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```

The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: There is much simpler solution with [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Comment: @Mr.Smith:- Hmm. Thats a duplicate. Though added. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, so why this question isn't closed yet?

Comment: @Mr.Smith:- Can only cast one vote ;)

Comment: My point is why are duplicates answered?

Comment: @Akshobhya:- If so then do accept the answer that helped you :)

Comment: @R.T. I have accepted :)

Comment: @Akshobhya:- Good. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you :) Since I am still learning I do make mistake :)

Comment: @Akshobhya:- We all do :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60886/discussion-between-akshobhya-and-r-t).

Comment: @Akshobhya:- Is there anything still left to be answered?

Comment: No.Nothing else Thanks :)

Comment: @Akshobhya:- You are welcome. You clicked on discussion on chat so I asked.